# How to find if data exists within a realm DB and compare this to a string?

Tags: android, android-studio, realm

I'm trying to implement a realm database within android studio, which stores user data such as their firstname, lastname, email address, etc. I have all of this stored within a class named DataModal.

I've then got my standard MainActivity class which is getting the value of an EditText component - this would be where the user enters their email address into a login phase of the application.

What I'm trying to do is get the class to read the email address values kept within the DB, and check if the email address that the user enters is already stored within the DB, however the getter that's within my DataModal class for email address isn't working and the checking of the result isn't working either.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? Thankyou :)

```
MainActivity:

> RealmQuery<DataModal> query = realm.where(DataModal.class);
                query.equalTo("emailAddress", emailAddress);
                RealmResults<DataModal> result = query.findAll();

                if (result.contains(emailString)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (!result.contains(emailString)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }`

`RealmQuery<DataModal> query = realm.where(DataModal.class);
                query.equalTo("emailAddress", emailAddress);
                RealmResults<DataModal> result = query.findAll();

                if (result.contains(emailString)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (!result.contains(emailString)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }`

DataModal: package com.example.mymedicare;

enter code hereimport io.realm.RealmObject;
import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey;
import io.realm.annotations.Required;

`enter code here`public class DataModal extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;
    private static String firstName;
    private static String lastName;
    private static String teleNum;
    private static String address;
    private static String GP;
    private static String emailAddress;
    private static String password;

    public DataModal(){

    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public static void setLastName(String lastName) {
        DataModal.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public static String getTeleNum() {
        return teleNum;
    }

    public static void setTeleNum(String teleNum) {
        DataModal.teleNum = teleNum;
    }

    public static String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public static void setAddress(String address) {
        DataModal.address = address;
    }

    public static String getGP() {
        return GP;
    }

    public static void setGP(String GP) {
        DataModal.GP = GP;
    }

    public static String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public static void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        DataModal.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public static String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public static void setPassword(String password) {
        DataModal.password = password;
    }

    public static String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public static void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        DataModal.firstName = firstName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. A couple of things jump out at me. First, please don't use capital letters on vars - Caps are reserved for Class, Struct and Enum names. vars used in code are always lower-cased. That's not the issue but it's Best Practice when coding. The issue is the var appears to be undefined here `.equalTo("EmailAddress", EmailAddress)` - what is `EmailAddress`? How is it populated. You should hve something like `String emailAddress == 'some email address string`. Please update your code with details

Comment: Thanks i appreciate it :) I was under the assumption that the second parameter I passed through was just the same EmailAddress from the DataModal class but I think I was wrong. EmailAddress is throwing an error though I assume for this reason.

Comment: Yep. Correct. The first parameter is the property name in quotes followed by the : and then the data of what you're looking for. See [Filters](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/java/examples/filter-data/#filters) in the docs for some examples.

Comment: I've altered my code a bit, I'll update the post with the new code, but the app is still showing the "Incorrect Email" toast notification. I'm just trying to compare what is already in the DB with what the user enters into the EditText, so the emailString parameter I passed through is where I've done the edit text of the email field .getText.toString and assigned it to that variable, thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: Your app doesn't know what the var `EmailAddress` is in `.equalTo("EmailAddress", EmailAddress) because it's not defined. Same thing with `emailString` here `query.equalTo("emailAddress", emailString)` because it's not defined. To be clear, those vars are only defined *inside the DataModal class* and nowhere else so the rest of your code won't be aware of those vars. You would need to, as I mentioned above, have some code like this `String emailString = my_datamodel_subclass.getEmailAddress`

Comment: I'm now getting this error:      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.mymedicare.DataModal.getEmailAddress()' on a null object reference
 after adding in "String emailS = dataModal.getEmailAddress", i've checked and the email address field within the DB has 3 seperate email addresses stored, is this meant to happen?

Comment: You're getting a bit beyond my skillset with Android here so as a guess the `result` is going to be zero, one or more dataModel objects and you would need to specify which one you want to call `getEmailAddress` on. e.g. results is never singular; it could have one object but that object will index 0 in results. The code in the question is a bit jumbled at this point so it's had to know what code actually running. I would suggest updating the question with your current code only and perhaps someone else with more Android experience can take a look.

Comment: @Jay okay no worries, thankyou for all of your help! I really appreciate it :D